# Sharepoint external list problem

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, external-content-type, external-list

I'm taking my first crack at creating an External list in SharePoint 2010. I've taken 3 training classes in SharePoint 2010, and am now trying to transfer my knowledge to my own development environment. I've followed the steps for creating my External Content type in Microsoft SharePoint Designer. I am connecting the External Content Type to a table in an external SQL Server Database. I've created a list specifying this External Content type. I've also given all authenticated users permission. I've verified that BCS is running, and all looks good. I've also checked and double checked the steps I used in creating the external content type and list by referring to the lab manual from my Sharepoint class.

When I try to navigate to display the list, I get this very informative error message:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server, administrator.
>
> Correlation ID:b7c91266-bbbc-4703-8704-beccbbd92de0

I've tried opening this page in Sharepoint Designer but this doesn't seem to help me. Has anyone experienced this problem before? Any gotcha's that I should be looking for?

I've also turned on detailed logging to look for some more information. I've searched for the correlation ID reported in the Sharepoint logs, but haven't found any matches.

Comment: Is this a single server deployment or multiple? Depending on how you configured the External data, ensure that user (BCS Service, current user or secure store) has permissions to SQL.

Comment: This is a Single Server farm. When I was setting up the external data type, I created a connection that I authenticated with a SQL user and password. Are you saying that in addition that the user that is configured to run the bcs service also has to have access to my SQL Server database that I'm accessing from the external Data type? This doesn't seem to make sense to me. If I were going to pull information from a third party, I may not be able to add them as a user to the third parties database.

Comment: Nope, I'm not saying that, I wanted to clarify how you were authenticating. Check out the last post on http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/cc05f9d6-b83b-4e43-8f5b-400dd16ff795